# window.open giving an error when clicking button to open new window

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open a new window and load a view file into that window. 
Here is my function for loading the view file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    self.LoadX12View - function () {
        window.open("x12Display.cshtml", "X12 Information", "height=600,width=800,addressbar=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=1,scrollbars=1");
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

This is my script with the button to call "LoadX12View"

```
<script type="text/html" id ="claimX12File-template">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: ClaimID"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: SubmittedOn"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: SubmittedBy"></td>
        <td><button class="btn" data-bind="click: LoadX12View">View</button></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

I can't seem to figure out why I keep getting an error when I click the button to open the new window.

Comment: Do you mean `self.LoadX12View = function () {`?

Comment: aha! that could be the issue.

Comment: You'll also want to use `"_blank"` for the second argument instead of the title of it. And for getting the right URL, there are four different ways. Without a slash (like you used) would mean if you're on a page like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819006, links would go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/x12Display.cshtml. To go to http://stackoverflow.com/x12Display.cshtml, the URL should be `/x12Display.cshtml` or `../x12Display.cshtml`. The other two types are specific to linking to resources of other domains/websites.

Comment: @Pluto Why do I want to use "_blank" for the second argument instead of the title?

Comment: The page title is defined in HTML, not when you open it. `"_blank"` means to open it in a new tab. There are some other predefined names, but other than that the purpose is to let you target that window in the future. For example if you open a second link the way you defined, it would change the location of the tab you previously opened (since you're using the same window name). This is useful for controlling popups. For example, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ezmzbyfc/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please include the error you are getting? I see some problems here but in order to solve this more info is needed.

First, is the path to the file correct? (x12Display.cshtml) that file should be at root lvl as I can see.
Another thing is that you have a typo in the code

```
self.LoadX12View - function () {
```

should be

```
self.LoadX12View = function () {
```

And last, but not least, are you sure you can load a .cshtml file in the browser without preprocessing it before?

Comment: well it looks like the type was what was causing the error because the button works. I was getting an object null error. Now i am trying to get the file path right.